# $T^2=I$ implies that $T$ is a normal operator

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to show that if $T$ is an operator in an inner product space over the complex field and  if $T^2=I$, then $T$ has to be normal.

Comment: This is false, e.g. $T(x,y)=(x+y,-y)$ on $\mathbb C^2$ with the standard inner product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is false. Let
$$T = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & -2 \\\ 0 & -1 \end{array} \right].$$

$T$ has eigenvalues $1, -1$ with eigenvectors $(1, 0), (1, 1)$ respectively, so satisfies $T^2 = I$. But the eigenspaces of $T$ are not orthogonal, so $T$ cannot be normal.